# Displaying React components on one page only

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building my first SPA with React but my React theory is not there yet. I have a Main component which renders a Header component. The Header component renders three components, Navigation, Claim and Bars. The problem is that Claim and Bars should be rendered only on homepage an not on other pages. Not really sure how to do it, I know I have to take it out from Main but not sure if I should work on the routes, if I put everything on the Homepage component or if there is a best practice for this.

**Routes.js**

```
var routes = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Main>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path="/services" component={Services}/>
    </Main>
 </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**Main.js component**

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
   return (
      <div className="wfp-grid" role="main">
        <div className="wfp-u-1">
          <Header />
          <div className="wavy"></div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**Header.js component**

```
var Header = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <header className="wfp-header-int">
        <Navigation />
        <Claim />
        <Bars />
     </header>
   );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Header` component you need to get current URL from the router and then render specific components according to the url

```
var Header = React.createClass({
    contextTypes: {
        router: React.PropTypes.object
    },

    render: () => {
        let curLocation = this.context.router.getCurrentLocation().pathname

        return (
            <header className="wfp-header-int">
            <Navigation />
            { curLocation === '/' && <Claim /> }
            { curLocation === '/' && <Bars /> }
         </header>
        )
    }
})
```

ps) this approach works for `react-router` v3, not sure if it works for v4

Comment: I am using v4, so I changed the value of curLocation = this.context.router.getCurrentLocation().pathname to curLocation = this.context.router.route.location.pathname and it works. Thanks.